# knitr + Rmd automate Date on title slide

Tags: html, r, knitr, pandoc

I would like to have a template of an .Rmd file that I use to make html5 slides.  Generally the beginning part of the template is:

```
% Title    
% Name    
% Date
```

I'd like to automatically fill in the Date so the template is always ready to go. (after running Pandoc as seen [here](http://yihui.name/en/2012/05/how-to-make-html5-slides-with-knitr/))

**This works but is hacky in that now date and name show in main html file (before html5 processing) because I had to remove the `%` before these elements:**

````
% Title    
Name    
`r as.character(format(Sys.Date(), format="%B %d, %Y"))`

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
# set global chunk options
opts_chunk$set(cache=TRUE)
library(knitr)
```
````

Maybe there's a non R, more html, fix.

Comment: typing the date costs at most 5 seconds... anyway, I did not quite understand why you had to remove `%`; isn't that required by Pandoc?

Comment: True Yihui but 5 seconds times hundreds of presentations; before you know it you're an old fart hobbling around lamenting the years of life spend typing those those ten characters.  Ok on a serious note the question was more is this possible.  Yeah the % thing baffled me too.  It doesn't seem to be needed by pandoc.  On my Windows box what I have above gives me what I want but leaving the `%` means their in the final slides.

Comment: Besides we have to make up for all the lost time we've pandered away with R (exhibit [A](http://yihui.name/en/2011/08/the-fun-package-use-r-for-fun/) and [B](http://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2012/07/29/hangman-in-r-a-learning-experience/)).

Comment: Honestly I have read this post 20 times but I still do not know what you were asking... What is the failure here and what is your expectation?

Comment: Yihui I wanted to include it as a template in the `reports` package.  So if you run `knitHTML` on the above code chunk and then the pandoc method you show you get this: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/61803503/example.html  This is what I want but I feel it's a hack in that the percent signs are not in front of  name or date.  I think this breaks rules that you're careful to adhere to and is not intuitive to change if the user wants a static date instead.  THis wasn't a big deal more of a curiosity.  If I put the percent signs back in like they're supposed to they show up on the slide.

Comment: You mean your own preference is without `%` before the date and author? And everything will be squeezed in the same `<h1></h1>`? That sounds like a bad choice. It looks bad in my eyes (author/date should be smaller than title), and it has bad consequences when you convert markdown to other formats like LaTeX. So really what is the point of removing `%`?

Comment: No not at all Yihui I want it to look like yours (e.g. the first code chunk I have above) but when I use this with `\`r as.character(format(Sys.Date(), format="%B %d, %Y"))\`` instead of date I get an error because it was used before the knitr code chunk (expected).  I think the answer may be to use an html date recognition rather than R.  I remove % because for some reason this makes the slide look as expected at least content wise.  I'm actually surprised it works at all since it's used before the knitr setup.

Comment: Ahhh... finally I see what is wrong there!! Answer coming in a minute. Next time you probably should call Dason and let him explain to me in person :)

Comment: Yeah he somehow seems to understand my language of babble :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This turns out to be a Pandoc problem, which was hidden so very deep that it took me quite a while to realize what was wrong there. The problem is that you have spaces in the end of the first two lines. In Pandoc's markdown, two or more spaces in the end of a line [means](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#paragraphs) a *line break*. Everything works if you remove the white spaces in the first two lines, e.g.

````
% Title
% Name
% `r as.character(format(Sys.Date(), format="%B %d, %Y"))`

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
# set global chunk options
opts_chunk$set(cache=TRUE)
library(knitr)
```
````

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks for bearing with me :)